# Network model with much more variables than samples

Tags: r, statistics

Dear stackoverflow forum,

this is more of a background question and I hope someone finds the time to give me an advice. 
The last few weeks I was learning on how to create a food web model depending on abundances of species (obtained by analysing genomic sequences from several places).

Given that this project was my actual start with this topic (i.e. coding, network modelling) I read very much, but could just understand a small part of it. Now I finally got the data and even if I filter it as much as maintainable there are more than 300 hundred species, but just 27 samples (not all species are present in every sample) and just 1-2 environmental parameters.

My first intention was to produce a food web which shows the strength of interaction & its direction, because the goal is to win knowledge about a uncharted biotope. **Do you think it is possible to create a statistical reliable food web (with R) based on this low information or at least a co occurrence network?** Because I got my doubts.. For example because working with the robust lm function would force me to restrict the number of species to 27 (samples).

If yes, a hint on how to, or some literature would make my day.

If this is the completely wrong place for this type of question, just tell me and I will delete it, but an advice for a better forum would be nice, maybe like stats.stackexchange?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: I found a related question, with an pretty nice answer: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/223486/modelling-with-more-variables-than-data-points